# => operator "undefined" error while trying to compare values in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm taking an introductory course on Javascript at my college and in my assignment, I had to write a function that took a value passed into the parameter and compares it through a switch statement.  This is what I did:

```
function grader(mark) {
  switch (mark) {
    case (mark >= 80 && mark <= 100) :
      return 'A';
      break;
    case (mark >= 70 && mark <= 79) :
      return 'B';
      break;
    case (mark >= 60 && mark <= 69) :
      return 'C';
      break;
    case (mark >= 50 && mark <= 59) :
      return 'D';
      break;
    case (mark >= 0 && mark <= 49) :
      return 'F';
      break;
  }
}
```

But the error I'm getting on scratchpad is this:

```
Exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'
@Scratchpad/2:3
*/

/*
undefined
*/
```

What does it mean when an operand is undefined?

Comment: Well that's not how `switch` statement cases work. You want an `if`/`else` tree.

Comment: I already got it.  Thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) cases cannot check a value in the range.

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
```

That clearly tells that the case should be a specific value.

You should go with tradational `if else if`

```
 if (mark >= 80 && mark <= 100){
      return 'A';
  }
  else if  (mark >= 70 && mark <= 79) {
     return 'B';
  }
```

Comment: Ah I see.  Is that specific to Javascript?

Comment: I see.  Thanks a lot.  I'll accept your answer.  If you think my question was well asked, can you upvote it? :)

Comment: @OnurOzbek you are welcome. You get upvotes automatically when you ask a good question. So no need to explicitly ask ;)